# How do I get my Puppet module's path?

Tags: shell, module, puppet, execution

A Puppet module of my application must execute a script that comes with that application. The directory layout is well-known, but the absolute path (of `src_root`) is variable.

```
src_root/
  my_script.sh <----+
  .puppet/          |
    modules/        |
      my_module/    |
        manifests/  | executes
          init.pp --+
```

Answer (score 0):

From where do you want to access the path of your environments?

If from a script, you can find it like so:

```
puppet config print| grep environmentpath
```

If from inside puppet, you have it in this variable: $::settings::environmentpath